# I'm developing together using Spring and Vue, and I have a few questions I'm posting

Tags: spring, vue.js

1. Vue is an SPA and I use a router, but in order to apply Spring security (due to page permissions, etc.), do I have to bring all the requests that switch to vue pages with the router to the server?
2. If No. 1 is correct, is there any data that can be used as a reference? And I wonder if it harms the advantages of SPA.

Comment: IMHO: You can just use @PreAuthorize to authorize rest endpoints if you need to authorize pages you can just ask permissions from backend and disable the pages that will not be reachable in Vue. SPA is client base so don't change it like to JSP

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.